# Tracing with tf.experimental.ExtensionType is not working in TensorFlow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I was reading the following from the TensorFlow.org:
Where possible, you should prefer converting the Python type into a tf.experimental.ExtensionType instead. Moreover, the TraceType of an ExtensionType is the tf.TypeSpec associated with it. Therefore, if needed, you can simply override the default tf.TypeSpec to take control of an ExtensionType's Tracing Protocol. Refer to the Customizing the ExtensionType's TypeSpec section in the Extension types guide for details.

Otherwise, for direct control over when Function should retrace in regards to a particular Python type, you can implement the Tracing Protocol for it yourself.

```
@tf.function
def get_mixed_flavor(fruit_a, fruit_b):
  return fruit_a.flavor + fruit_b.flavor

class Fruit:
  flavor = tf.constant([0, 0])

class Apple(Fruit):
  flavor = tf.constant([1, 2])

class Mango(Fruit):
  flavor = tf.constant([3, 4])

# As described in the above rules, a generic TraceType for `Apple` and `Mango`
# is generated (and a corresponding ConcreteFunction is traced) but it fails to 
# match the second function call since the first pair of Apple() and Mango() 
# have gone out out of scope by then and deleted.
get_mixed_flavor(Apple(), Mango()) # Traces a new concrete function
get_mixed_flavor(Apple(), Mango()) # Traces a new concrete function again

# However, each subclass of the `Fruit` class has a fixed flavor, and you
# can reuse an existing traced concrete function if it was the same
# subclass. Avoiding such unnecessary tracing of concrete functions
# can have significant performance benefits.

class FruitTraceType(tf.types.experimental.TraceType):
  def __init__(self, fruit_type):
    self.fruit_type = fruit_type

  def is_subtype_of(self, other):
      return (type(other) is FruitTraceType and
              self.fruit_type is other.fruit_type)

  def most_specific_common_supertype(self, others):
      return self if all(self == other for other in others) else None

  def __eq__(self, other):
    return type(other) is FruitTraceType and self.fruit_type == other.fruit_type

  def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.fruit_type)

class FruitWithTraceType:

  def __tf_tracing_type__(self, context):
    return FruitTraceType(type(self))

class AppleWithTraceType(FruitWithTraceType):
  flavor = tf.constant([1, 2])

class MangoWithTraceType(FruitWithTraceType):
  flavor = tf.constant([3, 4])

# Now if you try calling it again:
get_mixed_flavor(AppleWithTraceType(), MangoWithTraceType()) # Traces a new concrete function
get_mixed_flavor(AppleWithTraceType(), MangoWithTraceType()) # Re-uses the traced concrete function
```

So, based on the text given in the official tensorflow site, for making the tracing happen only once, instead of overriding **tf_tracing_type**, we can define Extension types in tensorflow. Here is a very simple code I wrote:

```
@tf.function
def get_mixed_flavor(fruit_a, fruit_b):
    print('tracing')
    return fruit_a.flavor + fruit_b.flavor

class Fruit:
    flavor: tf.Tensor

class FruitExtensionType(tf.experimental.ExtensionType, Fruit):
    pass

class Apple(FruitExtensionType):
    flavor: tf.Tensor = tf.constant([1, 2])

    class Spec:
        def __init__(self):
            self.flavor = tf.TensorSpec([2], dtype=tf.int32)

class Mango(FruitExtensionType):
    flavor: tf.Tensor = tf.constant([3, 4])

    class Spec:
        def __init__(self):
            self.flavor = tf.TensorSpec([2], dtype=tf.int32)


get_mixed_flavor(Apple(), Mango())  
get_mixed_flavor(Apple(), Mango())
```

In the provided code, the tracing again happens only once (I know the number of tracings from putting a print statement inside get_mixed_flavor() function). The problem is that even if I change:

```
class Apple(FruitExtensionType):
    flavor: tf.Tensor = tf.constant([1, 2])
```

to:

```
class Apple(FruitExtensionType):
    flavor: tf.Tensor = tf.constant([[[[1, 2]]]])
```

Or even change the data types, still tracing happens only once. Any idea on that? Thank you in advance!

I tried debugging the code and changing the dtypes, but still tracing happens only once when using the ExtensionTypes. I am using TF V2.X

Answer (score 0):

A lot of interesting things happens here!

First, when you override the inner `class Spec`, autograph takes the shape definition as the ground source of truth. This is exactly the mechanism by which you tell autograph: “I know better, the new shape of the tensor will still be compatible with a cached graph, even though the bottom-most fruit subclass is different. I swear that it has the same shape as the other fruit, so don't retrace if you have a cached trace of a suitable shape, but from a different fruit. Look, here's the new `TensorSpec`.” If the new tensor shape is compatible with an existing trace in the `GenericFunction`'s cache of `ConcreteFunction`s w.r.t. exact or wildcard dimensions, datatypes and the rank—and in your case there is—autograph will reuse it without retracing.

In the `class Apple.Spec` you have the shape of `flavor` member tensor hardcoded as [2], i. e. an 1×2 array of type `int32`:

```py
class Apple(FruitExtensionType):
  # . . . .
    class Spec:
        def __init__(self):
            self.flavor = tf.TensorSpec([2], dtype=tf.int32)
```

Since the shape is hardcoded, it's never going to change, and autograph will never retrace your function.

But then, why do you get the old result again and again? Because `tf.constant`s! You may think that the changed Apple's flavour, [[[1,2]]] of the wrong shape 1×1×1×2 would be passed to the function graph, and it will fail to bind with a TypeError exception. But in fact constants are “baked” into the graph. When your function was traced, line 4 turned into a graph which essentially does

```py
return tf.constant([1, 2]) + tf.constant([3, 4])
```

Your function in fact takes the arguments that each object's `.flavor` had when it was last traced! Since tensors are immutable (and `ExtensionType` is a subclass of `CompositeTensor`, in turn a subclass `Tensor`), and `.fruit` is the member of the class, not of an instance, autograph simply embeds the constants into the graph. They are considered absolutely immutable, as there is only one class object for Apple!

And, since the graph is never retraced, because you return the same `TensorSpec` every time, the new constant [[[1,2]]] never gets into any graph at all.

To run your sample into a real wreck, make `self.flavor` an *instance* field and initialize it with a random tensor. After the graph is traced (and it won't ever be retraced as long as you return the same `TensorSpec`), change the shape of the random tensor. In this case the graph will in fact be passed the tensor of an unexpected shape, and you'll get a `TypeError`, IIRC.

Overriding `Spec` is a very powerful mechanism, which eliminates essentially all checks, so be careful to return a correct `TensorSpec`s from it.